# How to restore booting on second Ubuntu-SSD after removing Win10-SSD from dual-boot system?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, ssd, windows-10, mbr

Most questions and answers I’ve seen so far (like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-do-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu)) are addressing solely booting problems after removing one OS from systems with a *single* SSD/HDD, but multiple partitions.

In my case, each OS has its own dedicated SSD and I assume that, after disconnecting the first Win10 SSD, the second Ubuntu SSD (which has been installed afterwards) does not boot maybe because of missing MBR.

Is there an way to fix booting on Ubuntu SSD alone, without OS reinstall?

Comment: Have you installed Ubuntu in BIOS mode or UEFI mode? When you have both the OS'es.. How are you selecting Windows? Via boot menu or grub?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I’m selecting via grub. I don’t remember for sure how I’ve installed it, but I think it was BIOS mode. But I’ll check it and come back.

Comment: can you type `sudo update-grub` command in terminal and post the output in your question please.

Comment: can you open Gparted from your Ubuntu and see /boot or /boot/efi is in both the devices or in one device like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBofP.png

Comment: output of `sudo update-grub`:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-34-generic
... ... ... ... ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 10 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done

Comment: Hi, Seems that Windows10 and Ubuntu both are installed in BIOS mode. Can you attach the gparted image also to proceed further.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1076564/739431 this answer is good. if you can access your hdd where Windows is present, just unplug it and reboot. system should boot to ubuntu. if not, plug the hdd back reboot and follow the answer in this comment. it probably should not make any issues.. in case, for safety, keep the bootable USB of your present Ubuntu version ready to reinstall the grub on SSD where Ubuntu is present.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've already tried to unplug Win SSD, but system did not boot on Ubuntu. Regarding GParted: /dev/sdb1 (Ubuntu SSD) has mount point "/" and no flags;  /dev/sda1 (Win SSD) has boot flag, but mounting point column is not shown at all.

Comment: OK.. Then when you are on Ubuntu.. Install grub on SSD with that answer.

Comment: @PRATAP it worked as described in the second answer (legacy BIOS => just install grub on Ubuntu SSD) from the question you’ve sent me. You may answer it and I’ll mark it as the solution

Comment: Hi, thanks for informing me about your success. You may up vote the answer from the linked question in the comment section above which helped you. Thank you once gain.

Comment: Can you try boot priority as windows SSD first. So that it will directly take you to Windows10. Later Change Boot Priority to Ubuntu SSD. It confirms that in future even if you remove Ubuntu SSD system will directly boot to Windows.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the answer. Unfortunately I’ve already erased the Win10 SSD, right after removing it from the PC