# Booting issues after deleted Windows on dual boot system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I had a dual booted system with Windows and Ubuntu. I wanted to remove Windows so I deleted all the Windows partitions (Even the System Reserve) which in retrospect I shouldn't have(?). So now when I try to boot I get the following message :

> BootDevice Not Found.
>   Please Install an Operating System on your Hard disk
>   Hard Disk - (3F0)

When I ran `boot-repair` I got:

> The boot of your PC is in EFI mode, but no EFI partition was detected. You may want to retry after creating a EFI partition (FAT32, 100MB-250MB, start of the disk, boot flag)

What I am thinking now is to move the sda5 by around 200Mb and make an EFI partition there. Would that help?

Current state of my partitions
[image]

Comment: @PRATAP Thanks a ton for helping. Could you explain to me what exactly is the problem? Was grub on the system reserve partition that I wrongfully deleted?

Comment: @PRATAP Sorry but I am a novice at this. Does changing boot mode to BIOS mean `legacy` boot mode?

Comment: @PRATAP I checked my boot configuration and under the option `Configure Legacy Support and Secure Boot` there was `Legacy Support Enable and Secure Boot Disable`. I guess this means Legacy Boot mode is enabled? 
If not how should I go about doing that. (HP Laptop)

Comment: I don't remember. It's been a very long time. But the results of boot-repair indicate that the boot is in EFI mode right? I had windows 10 and I am not sure about the boot mode but I think it was EFI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85246/discussion-between-rohit-sarkar-and-pratap).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had removed that partition that had my Grub. 
Hence to solve it I made an EFI System Partition.

[This](http://askubuntu.com/a/1076535/739431) excellent answer explains how to do that.

Also after this was done I had to change the boot options of my System to use UEFI instead of Legacy.