# Modify boot option name in BIOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios

context: uefi, GRUB, BIOS

I have a Pavilion Power CB015 laptop. *I want to modify the BIOS boot option label*. Currently I have a windows 10 on the first hard drive (sda) and an Ubuntu 18 on the second hard drive (sdb). But in my Bios boot menu, the option is showed as *Ubuntu on sda* but not *Ubuntu on sdb*.

@ I can change the names in GRUB menu by using *GRUB Customizer* but I don't know how to change the name in Bios menu. It happens when I installed the new Ubuntu 18 on the sdb and deleted the old Ubuntu 16 which located on sda.

Picture for Reference
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: why do you think `sda` is named dedicated for Windows10? when you have multiple disks the system decides what to call. when it is showing ubuntu on sda, have you tried to read for "windows boot manager on sdb" in grub menu selection window?

Comment: In Bios menu I have Ubuntu on sda or Windows boot manager on sda.

Comment: can you share a pic of it please.

Comment: Pls find it here:https://drive.google.com/file/d/12AKS5XlC2yHKR5Dlqwo_5WM7qYW4qkVV/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Hi, pic gave a clue. when you installed Ubuntu as a dual OS with Windows..the same EFI System Partition is used for both. that is why it shows like that. even though your / partition of Ubuntu is on another drive..the base is at Windows drive.

Comment: changing of the name in BIOS -> Boot Option menu is purely dependent on the BIOS vendor, i dont think such facility is provided by the vendors. if worked out well, may be the text "ubuntu" can be possible but not the format <KXG50ZNV256G TOSHIBA> if you want to see Ubuntu option on Other Drive name, you need to Install EFI System Partition on that drive.

Comment: if you decided to create a separate EFI System Partition for Ubuntu on other drive, this may help https://askubuntu.com/a/1076535/739431

Comment: Thank you so much PRATAP, pls re-post your solution as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PRATAP Jan 12 at 13:18 
changing of the name in BIOS -> Boot Option menu is purely dependent on the BIOS vendor, i dont think such facility is provided by the vendors. if worked out well, may be the text "ubuntu" can be possible but not the format  if you want to see Ubuntu option on Other Drive name, you need to Install EFI System Partition on that drive.
if you decided to create a separate EFI System Partition for Ubuntu on other drive, this may help askubuntu.com/a/1076535/739431