# Increase disk partition with Ubuntu live cd and gparted

Tags: gparted

[image: photo]

I am new to Linux and I have created a dual boot with windows 10 inside a SSD, in the start I did a partition of 20 gb believing that it would be just for the system and it would be possible to use the memory leftover without needing to do anything else, so now my system is almost full and I've tried to extend the partition through the gparted unallocating 50 gb of my SSD, but even with the new unallocated space it is not possible to extend through the resize option, what should I do to extend it? And is it possible for me to use the memory from an HD too?

Comment: Welcome! Could you post a screenshot of gparted? Use the image tool to add it to the post.

Comment: I've updated with the image

Comment: Move the EFI System Partition to the left of the unallocated space first. Then resize the Ubuntu system partition.

Comment: @user68186 True. [This will help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076448/moving-grub-to-a-new-drive-to-get-rid-of-windows)

Comment: Thanks @user68186 I extended it now

Comment: It is possible for me to use the HD space with this system?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use the HDD with the SSD no problem. Just partition it and use it.

Comment: I don't understand this question. You are already using the SSD. Do you have a different HDD? If so ask a new question about the HDD. Indicate how you want to use the HDD in the new question.

Comment: Now that you've made a change, would you mind, please, opening a terminal window, and at a shell prompt, do `sudo parted -l` so we can see the current partitions on both drives? Once you've run that, please highlight and copy the results, then come back here, click [edit], and paste them into your question. It's far easier to read text data than to squint at a screenshot of a GUI, and, besides, you've made changes.

Comment: When you paste the text from the terminal don't forget to format it as `code` by using the { } icon above the edit window.