# How to rebuild removed efi boot loader in ubuntu and windows

Tags: uefi, 20.04, windows-10

I have installed 3 operating systems on my computer(windows, ubuntu and cent os).
While installing centos I realized that my efi boot loader has been removed, and I can't access any operating system.
How can I rebuild/fix efi boot partition?
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving Grub to a new drive to get rid of Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076448/moving-grub-to-a-new-drive-to-get-rid-of-windows)

Answer (score 0):

An EFI partition is a fat32 (or fat12 or fat 16) formatted partition with a specific partition type identifier. Can create such partition with partitoning tools. Then reinstall Grub. Here on Askubuntu, a [detailed walk trough](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076448/moving-grub-to-a-new-drive-to-get-rid-of-windows) is provided where an EFI partition is created, and then Grub is reinstalled on the drive containing the new EFI.